# Clear coat is not glossy

Tags: paint-clearcoat

I had some deep scratches on front bumper and some other problems with rust on car. So I decided to fix it at home as car probably has lower value then actual proper paint job would cost.

1. I sanded down paint and scratches
2. I used elastic polyester filler designed for plastic bumpers and sanded down all unperfections
   [image: filler]
3. I used primer filler.
   [image]
4. After 2-3 weeks I got back to car and sanded down all transition between primer and untouched paint. Then I cleared everything with isopropanol and dust cleaners. Then I applied 3 layers of metalic paint in prefilled spray can from ColorMatic. 
   [image: prefilled paint]
5. After 30 minutes as was written on label, I applied 3 layers of clear coat from spray can - Colormatic 2k Clear coat
   [image: ColorMatic 2k clear coat]

Now the result is not what I expected. I expected it to be glossy, but instead of it, it is looking really strange when comparing to original car coat. 
I have been spraying everything insinde my garage which is inside house and heated. And I have been putting spray cans in warm water before using them.

[image: result]

What could cause this result? 
Last thing I can try now is to wetsand and polish the clear coat, but I am not sure if it would help ...

Comment: From what distance were you spraying?

Comment: If you have enough clear coat on there, and as long as you have the right equipment, I think you should be able to fix it. I would suggest using a *compound* instead of sanding it (I believe wet sanding is for taking out deep scratches), and then polish over it. Just to be safe, perhaps start on a small area first to see if the compound clears up the paint any, before doing all the work on the rest of your bumper.

Comment: have you done any polishing/finishing work on that yet?

Comment: was it a damp day when you did this? moisture in the air can make a difference...